# You need a cylinder that holds   , what dimension minimize coast?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

You need a cylinder that holds $2000\pi\textrm{cm}^3$, what dimension minimize coast?

[image]

hello

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? This looks like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not just post homework/exam problems. Show us what you've tried and ask a specific question about where you got stuck. Moreover, this sort of problem appears in literally every introductory calculus book.

Comment: Also, the hints in the right column step you through the solution. Have you started at the top?

Comment: This is a badly designed problem because it does not state how costs are incurred. The hints suggest that you have to cut from a sheet of metal of infinitesimal thickness and they want you to minimise the area of the sheet metal used. However they don't say how much it costs to join the metal together at the seams. Neither do they tell you if there is a cost to the waste material when you cut from the sheet, especially the disks for the ends. Without the hints, it could be very confusing for a practically-minded person.